StepVerifier 'expectAccessibleContext' makes code not execute
Can any explain why this code fails with "java.lang.AssertionError: Expected value Hey for key OID, key not present":
@Test
void name() {
    StepVerifier.create(Mono.just("Start")
                    .map(val -> Optional.of(val)).defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty()) // <---- point of interest
                    .flatMap(val -> Mono.just(val).then().contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(OID, "Hey"))))
            .expectAccessibleContext()
            .contains("OID", "Hey")
            .then()
            .verifyComplete();
}

The flatMap is never executed.
The code succeeds if I'm removing "point of interest":
@Test
void name() {
    StepVerifier.create(Mono.just("Start")
                    .flatMap(val -> Mono.just(val).then().contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put(OID, "Hey"))))
            .expectAccessibleContext()
            .contains("OID", "Hey")
            .then()
            .verifyComplete();
}

My clear idea is that expectAccessibleContext() may be what causes this odd behaviour. But I don't have any good reason why.
StepVerifier to succeed

Are you sure that the second code sample is exactly what you have in the test?

Hi Igor. Yes. I mean, I have simplified the code down to the minimum to make it clear that nothing else made the trouble, and for you easily to read.
But the first scenario still fails if I run it, and the second passes.

Thank you for confirmation. So I've just tried this exact code and I surprised that the second example works, but the first one fails. This is strange and I guess I still don't understand how reactor works.

Then we apparently are two.
I was hoping an Reactor expert had some insights. To me this is unlogical.
